# deploying a standard build of wordpress in WHM/cPanel

Tags: admin

An admin question:

I would like to know if there is a way to deploy a standard build of Wordpress in a WHM/cPanel environment?

Standard features I'd personally like to include are a set of common plugins I use for each Wordpress site I build.

I have searched for `standard build of wordpress` and found nothing relevant.

Installing MainWP Child, and adding the site to MainWP Dashboard is one solution I have at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have SSH access you can write `wp-cli` based scripts to instull whatever you want.

In theory you can also extend WHM/Cpanel to do that, but that is more of what hosting company will do and probably not relevant to "end users"